# What is the structure of JPA repository method name for the column type array?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data

I'm using postgresSQL as database. In my table `nicknames_dictionary` there is a column `nicknames` with data type `text[]`.
I want to search multiple `nicknames` whether it is inside array or not using the JPARepository for the same. So I want to know what method name I should add in `JPARepository` interface.

The query that I run on postgres is : `SELECT  * FROM nicknames_dictionary  WHERE  nicknames = ARRAY['jo'];`

Ive tried with method name `List<NicknamesDictionary> findByNicknamesIn(Collection<String> nicknames);` but it gave error as `java.lang.String cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;`. Looked into the official [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation), but unable to find structure for this kind of query.

**Entity class**:

```
@Entity
@Table(
        name = "nicknames_dictionary"
)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class NicknamesDictionaryEntity {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="nicknames_id_generator", sequenceName="nicknames_dictionary_id_seq", allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator="nicknames_id_generator")
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @Type(type = "com.ash.entity.GenericStringArrayUserType")
    @Column(name = "nicknames")
    private String[] nicknames;

    //getters & setters

}
```

**GenericStringArrayUserType.java**:

```
public class GenericStringArrayUserType<T extends Serializable> implements UserType {

    protected static final int[] SQL_TYPES = {Types.ARRAY};
    private Class<T> typeParameterClass;

    @Override
    public int[] sqlTypes() {
        return new int[]{Types.ARRAY};
    }

    @Override
    public Class<T> returnedClass() {
        return typeParameterClass;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object x, Object y) throws HibernateException {

        if (x == null) {
            return y == null;
        }
        return x.equals(y);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(Object x) throws HibernateException {
        return x.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet resultSet, String[] names, SessionImplementor session, Object owner)
            throws HibernateException, SQLException {

        if (resultSet.getArray(names[0]) == null) {
            return new String[0];
        }

        Array array = resultSet.getArray(names[0]);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T javaArray = (T) array.getArray();
        return javaArray;
    }

    @Override
    public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement statement, Object value, int index, SessionImplementor session)
            throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        Connection connection = statement.getConnection();
        if (value == null) {
            statement.setNull(index, SQL_TYPES[0]);
        } else {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            T castObject = (T) value;
            Array array = connection.createArrayOf("text", (Object[]) castObject);
            statement.setArray(index, array);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object deepCopy(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMutable() {
        return true;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public Serializable disassemble(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return (T) this.deepCopy(value);
    }

    @Override
    public Object assemble(Serializable cached, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
        return this.deepCopy(cached);
    }

    @Override
    public Object replace(Object original, Object target, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
        return original;
    }
}
```

**Repository Class**:

```
public interface NicknamesDictionaryRepository extends JpaRepository<NicknamesDictionaryEntity, Long> {

    List< NicknamesDictionaryEntity> findByNicknamesIn(Collection<String> nicknames);
}
```

Let me know what will be the correct syntax for the method name or if there is another way to do it. (Yes, at the end I can use the `criteriabuilder` if unable to solve it using method name)

Comment: Is this your actual code? shouldn't you return a list of `NicknameDictionaryEntity` instead of `NicknameDictionary`?

Comment: This is not actual code. I've created copy of actual scenario I'm facing. (edited return type)